# VB.NET: Output all Windows.Media.Brushes

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, system.windows.media, wpf-brushes

I have some shapes on an WPF in VB.Net. I added a handler, so I'm able to delete or edit the shapes with my controls. For that I added an combobox where I wanna display all Windows.Media.Brushes so I can select one and add the color to the shape.

My Question:
- How can I add all names of the Windows.Media.Brushes to a combobox?
- How to coverte the names later back to a brush?

Best Regards,
Stan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of all brush names just filter the properties of `Brushes` by their type

```
var brushes = typeof(Brushes).GetProperties()
                             .Where (pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(SolidColorBrush))
                             .Select (pi => pi.Name)
                             .ToList();
```

to turn a name back into a brush you can use reflection again:

```
var brush = typeof(Brushes).GetProperty("Blue")
                           .GetValue(null) 
                as SolidColorBrush;
```

Comment: Another way to convert string to SolidColorBrush is use `BrushConverter` (use `ConvertFrom` or `ConvertFromString` method). This is how the designer parses color name to brush in XAML.

Comment: Cheers Stanley I could adopt your code to VB.NET to get the whole list of collers. Thank's King I am using your code to convert the colors later. The adopted Code looks like this:       For Each brush In GetType(Brushes).GetProperties()
            comboBrushes.Items.Add(brush.Name)
        Next